# How I can update a widget with animated text after a setState()?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

So, I'm trying to update an animated text in a bar after edit some entity values. In fact, I add or delete "labels" from a post, but when I go back to the post view, the animated text just throw the following error (I'm using the animated_text_kit plugin) in both cases (add or delete):

```
The following RangeError was thrown building ScaleAnimatedTextKit(dirty, dependencies: [_EffectiveTickerMode], state: _ScaleTextState#07f27(tickers: tracking 3 tickers)):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2
```

It's like the widget it's not rebuilding when I did a setState() from a child widget (the one's that edit the post).
I tried with another plugin, but it was worse, I tried to create a variable "bar" with "AnimatedText" type, that try to "updates" when I called setState() but doesn't work.

Here is the code from the widget to edit (just the part with the query):

```
class EditPost extends StatefulWidget {
  Post post;
  List<String> values;
  String description;
  int cant;
  bool must_be_seen;
  final Function() notifyParent;
  createState() => _EditPostState();
  EditPost({Key key, @required this.notifyParent ,@required this.post,@required this.values,@required this.description,@required this.cant,@required this.must_be_seen}) : super(key: key);
}

class _EditPostState extends State<EditPost> {
  //query para crear post
  Future<void> editPost() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString('email');
    Map data = {
      'description': widget.description,
      'labels' : widget.values
    };
    ...
```

Below its the code for the widget bar that's animated:

```
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:animated_text/animated_text.dart';

class LabelsBar extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<String> labels;

  LabelsBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.labels,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LabelsBarState createState() => _LabelsBarState();
}

class _LabelsBarState extends State<LabelsBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ScaleAnimatedTextKit(
        repeatForever: true,
        onTap: () {
          print("Tap Event");
        },
        text: widget.labels,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart // or Alignment.topLeft
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I show the bar:

```
...
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
 
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new LabelsBar(labels: widget.post.labels),
                    
                  ),
 ),
...
```

In that widget I have the refresh method too, that I called in the child widget when I wanna edit:

```
  refresh() {
  setState(() {});
  }
```

I know that there's no problem with the edit widget, cause' if a refresh the view or I just go a little up/down the error is gone, but I need to show the result of an edit without that error.

this is how normally looks like

[image]

this is what I see when I add/delete some labels

[image]

When I refresh, everything goes back to the normal and the new labels are there or the ones that I deleted aren't. I think that there's is an issue in the plugin code (https://github.com/aagarwal1012/Animated-Text-Kit/blob/master/lib/src/scale.dart) but I don't know what I have to modify.

Comment: It's very hard to follow your snippets. Can you provide a [mcve]?